# Finding all combination of numbers to sum without repetition

Tags: vba, excel

I want to get all combination of numbers to sum.

My input is X that is variable and X is the number of numbers,

For example:

`X=4` means we have `1,2,3,4`

`x=100 means 1,2,3,4,5,,98,99,100`

Now I want to get `{(1,2)(1,3)(1,4)(2,3)(2,4)(3,4),(1,2,3)(1,3,4)…}`

We can’t have repetitive sequence like `(1,2)(2,1)(1,2,3)(1,3,2)`

I want to get all combinations that these numbers can be sum without repetitive sequence.

Can anyone help me to find it’s algorithm? I must code it in VBA of Excel using for loops

Comment: See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/combin-function-HP010062427.aspx  I calculate there are approx. 1x10^29 ways just to choose 50 numbers from 100, so I'd be interested how you will store all of these combinations!

Comment: I only ask because this sounds like a school assignment, do you actually need to store all combinations or just find a count of them?

Comment: I need all combination not a count of them

Comment: poor question. Have you tried to come up with an algorithm? This sounds like homework and we do not do peoples homeworks.

Comment: No it isn't homework ,i do accounting works and i need this algorithm for my work I'm not student :)

Answer (score 1):

the "algorithm" is solved from Maths and given by the combinations of X by 2:

```
X!/((X-2)!*2!)=X!/((X-2)!*2)

(note: Just in case... "!" is the factorial...)
```

now if you want to use `for-loop` to calculate factorial (written in c):

```
int main()

{

    int num,factorial=1;

    cout<<" Enter Number To Find Its Factorial:  ";

    cin>>num;

    for(int a=1;a<=num;a++)

    {

        factorial=factorial*a;

    }
```

Comment: I am aware, I am just not that familiar with VBA, I suppose he can make a "translation"

Comment: i need algorithm it can be other programming language